# How to create a matrix of sequence of numbers in R that goes from column to column than row to row?

Tags: r, matrix, sequence

If i run this command :-
A = matrix(data=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),ncol=3)

I get something like this

```
    A
        [,1] [,2] [,3]
  [1,]    1    3    5
  [2,]    2    4    6
```

What if i wanted it like this:-

```
   A
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    2    3
 [2,]    4    5    6
```

and did not want to disturb the sequence of numbers in the code

```
 (A = matrix(data=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),ncol=3))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `byrow` argument in `matrix` function.

```
matrix(data=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),ncol=3,byrow = T)
```